# Optimisation For Currency Conversion Program

Tags: python-3.x

*As said in the title, I am creating a currency exchange program*

I want to create a program that converts every single type of currency into another but I'm not sure the most efficient way of doing it

**My Thinking**

My intial plan was to create functions for all currency conversions and create if statements that would execute the function when both conditions are true. But this will take me ages...

```
# what currency they want to exchange
currency = input("What currency would you like to exchange: ").lower()

# what currency they want to exchange to
exchange_currency = input("What currency would you like to exchange to: ").lower

# how much they want to exchange
amount_of_currency = input("How much %s would you like to exchange: " % (currency))

# calculates pound to dollar
def pound_to_dollars(amount_of_currency):
result = float(amount_of_currency) * 1.28
print("That would be",result,exchange_currency)

# calculation takes place if both conditions are true
if currency == "pound" or "£" and exhange_currency == "dollar" or "$":
pound_to_dollars(amount_of_currency)
```

**Questions**

Is there a way to have one function that would be able to take care of all the conversions?

How would you guys go about creating a currency conversion system efficiently?

Comment: Try having a common base currency, such as USD, and have conversion rates for every other currency with respect to USD. Then, when you want to convert, use these conversion rates.

Comment: @NitinPawar But what if they wanted to convert pound to euro for example?

Comment: So you first convert pound to USD and then the same USD to euro

Comment: @NitinPawar ohhhhh i get it that would work i guess

Comment: Or just have a 2 dimensional matrix (using `numpy` for example) that stores all the rates for all the currencies independently.

Comment: Sqoshu Thanks for the suggestion. I'll definitely look into matrices

Comment: Please upvote the comments you find relevant or useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# build a dictionary of rates
exchange_rates = {
    # MADE UP RATES
    ("USD", " EUR"): .85,
    ("BRL", "YEN"): 150,
    # Add as desired
}

def convert(original_currency, new_currency):
    # get the relevant rate from the dictionary
    rate = exchange_rates[(original_currency, new_currency)]
    # prompt user for how much he wants to exchange. 
    user_value = raw_input("How much would you like to exchange {}? ".format(original_currency))
    # explicitly define type of input
    amount = float(user_value)
    # perform conversion
    conversion = amount * rate
    print " %s %s is equal to %s %s." % (user_value, original_currency, conversion, new_currency)
```

If you notice, all of those x_currency_to_y_currency functions all have a similar structure, this is typically a sign that a more general purpose function can be made to perform a task. This concept in programming falls under the term "DRY" an acronym for "Don't repeat yourself".

An example use of this function would look like:

```
convert('USD', 'EUR')
```

Which would output "x USD is equal to y EUR" where x is amount of currency to convert input by the user.